# Create a new facet block from Taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

Hi I am using recruiter distribution, I have creates a new taxonomy named as trades, having few terms, Now I want to create a facet block from these taxonomy terms, could anyone please suggest me any tutorial for doing this. I already have few default facet blocks provided by recruiter distribution. I could not find any proper tutorial regarding creation of facet from taxonomy terms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for creating facet blocks :[Faceted search using search api tutorial](http://cheppers.com/blog/faceted-search-search-api-drupal)

To add a taxonomy term as a facet just check the fields tab to find your term field and enable it and after enabling it you have to re-index and now your facet can be rendered as a block !!!

Comment: Thats cool...!! Mark it as answered then..